# Performance problems in Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I am currently working in a relatively large project, built with AngularJs. One part of the application is a is a form that you can add any number of pages to (and unfortunately, a lot of unnecessary crap is added) , i.e. the object representing the model for the form can grow very large. At some point, Chrome basically can't handle it, and it takes 10 -20 seconds to get a field focused, or to push a button. Firefox, on the other hand, can manage at least 5 times as much quite smoothly.

My question is, what could be the reason for this? Is it large objects in general? Could it be due to a bad implementation with Angular?

Comment: how large can the object be? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Not sure how to measure it, but when the problem occurs, it's about 1,000,000 characters.

Comment: wow, that is huge.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using, it is best to stay current. But you can't control your users versions so you need to prevent or fix this

Comment: I'm using Version 50.0.2661.102 (64-bit), but yes, the problem should be fixed, regardless of which version a person is using. Different computers seems to have problems att different stages though.

Answer (score 1):

There are some very powerful features in Chrome DevTools for analysing the performance of you apps, including the Timeline and Profile panels.

**Timeline ([How to use the Timeline Tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool?utm_source=dcc))**
[image: Timeline]

**Profile ([Speed Up JavaScript Execution](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/rendering-tools/js-execution))**
[image: Profile]

It is possible that the object is simply too large for the amount of memory there is, but it is also quite possible that you can optimise the rendering of the components to reduce the lag. Layout is often a cause of performance problems. You can read more about [Rendering performance](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

Probably splitting that object into several smaller ones may help.
Also may be difference in performance between `object.foo` and `object['foo']`.
Also try to avoid deep nesting in your structure.
Theoretically some parts of your structure can be dynamically return by functions on demand, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok without seeing some code, it's hard to tell you exactly why it's super slow or what can be done to speed it up. But considering you said that the object is *huge*, i guess angular is struggling with all the bindings during digest cycle.

So, here are some of the performance tunings you can do to try to speed up the app a bit.

1. Avoid using watchers when ever you can.

   And when watching arrays, maybe use `$watchCollection`(shallow watch) instead of `$watch`(which will deep watch the array)
2. When using `ng-repeat`, try not to load all items at once. Paginate when ever you can. Maybe some sort of infinite scroll? [ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/)
3. Avoid using filters when ever you can, especially in `ng-repeat`s with a lot of items.
4. Avoid binding `ng-if`, `ng-show` etc to functions that do heavy processing because then these get evaluated during every digest cycle.
5. Use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` when you can. This removes element from dom and destroys all watchers as well.
6. Use *one time bindings* where possible. This pretty much updates the UI once and then forgets about the model it's binded to (thus avoiding watcher).

   This can be dome by adding `::` to your bindings

   Example: `{{::myModel}}`

   A good article on one time binding: [thoughtgram](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html)
7. `$interval` can be evil if not used carefully. Every time $interval *ticks*, it triggers a digest cycle. In some cases, this might not be needed and can be turned off by passing in `false` as the 4th parameter.

   `$interval(fn, delay, [count], [invokeApply], [Pass])`

   More info here: [official $interval docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)
8. And last but not least, PROFILE you app.

   Like @Gideon has metioned, use google chrome profiling tool to identify parts of the application that are taking too much time to execute and optimise them.

   Built in profiler is good but consider using something like [batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en) specifically made for profiling angular apps.

Note: [this](https://github.com/shahata/angular-viewport-watch) might be worth looking into as well. An angular directive that can be used to turn off watchers for elements in ng-repeat when they are not in view. (I haven't tried it myself but looks ok)