# Long array list rendering makes page scrolling slow in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, arraylist, angularjs-ng-repeat

When trying to render more than 120 items from an array (with images) the **scrolling** of the list becomes slower. Basically, when I am loading new data in infinite scroll, I am concatenating old array data with new array data.

On the other hand, popular websites like dribbble, behance dont seem to have this issue. Maybe this issue is specific to Angular.js? Has anyone faced this problem in their projects?

Comment: The main point to understand here is you are loading data from server or local ? and if its in local you can use limitTo filter rather than concatination

Comment: Perhaps have a look at a directive like [ngInfiniteScroll](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html) to progressively load the items you need rather than all at once

Comment: Happened with me when I had a bulky array rendered using `ng-repeat` but without `track by`. See if you are missing that

Comment: If you're looking at tips to improve performance, here's a post i've made earlier which talks about some of the things you could try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38349146/841804

Comment: ng-repeat is great but when Array has more than 20-30 elements it become painfully slow. I read somewhere that is because of re-render all items in every update. 

You could try use one time bindings but it helps only a little. 

When we bulid Chat App instead of angular ng-repeat We have to use pure JS to list messages.

Comment: Javascript is definitely an impact on performance but you must improve your querying performance as well. I faced same issues and I developed photo application with same concept, where I can retrieve photos among more than 1 lakhs records. So please first analyse your querying performance also.

Comment: @VinodLouis its in server. We are more concerned about efficiently rendering the array. This is what we are doing: 1. We are rendering 120 objects with images at a time 2. When a user scrolls down, we are appending each fetch to this list of 120 objects, which is making the list bigger and the application slows down drastically.

Comment: @haxxxton We are actually loading progressively, but when number of items in the array ( which also contains images) increases to say (about 400) the scrolling becomes very slow. Here's the website URL if you are wondering : www.3dxtool.com ( its a test site)

Comment: @tanmay trackby is already in place. Any other suggestions? :)

Comment: @shrbisht, using the ngInfiniteScroll plugin dynamically loads and unloads items. If this includes images, they should be pulled from browser cache easily enough to save loading them all again. This means based upon your screen size, you're possibly only loading 50 items at any one time..

Comment: @DominikRuczyński Your advice came very close to the solution but we are still struggling to find the best way around this. Could you help some more please? Whats the best way to use Pure JS in this situation? This is the test site (www.3dxtool.com) . If you see the site, you will notice the rendering is really really slow once you have scrolled down to 180 -200 items.

Comment: @shrbisht, if you can supply your code in something like jsfiddle or plunkr so that we can test.. providing a "live" example makes it incredibly difficult to debug

Comment: @haxxxton This method seems promising. We are giving it a try :) Do you think there's any other way around this? ( In case this gets a little complicated to achieve in my very short deadline )

Comment: @shrbisht i see 2 ways of do that. 
1) as i wrote - use pure javascript. remove ng-repeat and add new elements to list with something like:
 `var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
para.appendChild(node);`
//example from w3schools
then in pure JS add events on click, classes etc. Its not perfect but we successful use that solution in interactive chat app. 

2) use pseudo pagination - keep only new items in array. You will need loading new elements also on scroll up.

Comment: http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2013/07/angularjs-my-solution-to-the-ng-repeat-performance-problem/ take a look at this OP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**INFINITE SCROLLING IN ANGULARJS**

No need of any additional plugins.

```js
app = angular.module("demo", []);

app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http){
  
  // the array which represents the list
  $scope.items = ["1. Scroll the list to load more"];
  $scope.loading = true;
  
  // this function fetches a random text and adds it to array
  $scope.more = function(){
    $http({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=2&start-with-lorem=1"
    }).success(function(data, status, header, config){
      
      // returned data contains an array of 2 sentences
      for(line in data){
        newItem = ($scope.items.length+1)+". "+data[line];
        $scope.items.push(newItem);
      }
      $scope.loading = false;
    });
  };
  
  // we call the function twice to populate the list
  $scope.more();
});

// we create a simple directive to modify behavior of <ul>
app.directive("whenScrolled", function(){
  return{
    
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
    
      // we get a list of elements of size 1 and need the first element
      raw = elem[0];
    
      // we load more elements when scrolled past a limit
      elem.bind("scroll", function(){
        if(raw.scrollTop+raw.offsetHeight+5 >= raw.scrollHeight){
          scope.loading = true;
          
        // we can give any function which loads more elements into the list
          scope.$apply(attrs.whenScrolled);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
li{
  display:block;
  list-style-type:none;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

ul{
  height:250px;
  background: #44E394;
  color: #fff;
  overflow:auto;
  width:550px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: 1px dashed #11BD6D;
  &::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width:8px;
    background-color:transparent;
  };
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color:#b0fccd;
    border-radius:10px;
  }
  &::-moz-scrollbar{
    width:8px;
    background-color:transparent;
  };
  &::-moz-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color:#b0fccd;
    border-radius:10px;
  }
  &::-ms-scrollbar{
    width:8px;
    background-color:transparent;
  };
  &::-ms-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color:#b0fccd;
    border-radius:10px;
  }
}

body{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.2em;
  font-family: "Helvetica";
  color: #44E394;
  background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAG0lEQVQIW2P88OHDfwY0wAgSFBAQYEQWp1AQAKUbE9XRpv7GAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app='demo'>
  <div data-ng-controller='MainController'>
    <ul class='hello' when-scrolled='more()'>
      <li data-ng-repeat='item in items'>
        {{item}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div data-ng-show='loading'>Loading</div>
  </div>
</div>
<h1>INFINITE SCROLLING IN ANGULARJS</h1>
```

Comment: This should have been the answer ! Better way to resolve scrolling list issues given slight change in directive implementation but good answer.

Answer (score 6):

`ngInfiniteScroll` is just a directive that you can use to implement infinite scrolling and it doesn't affect this problem.

**here are some tips to speed up the app**

- **Avoid using watchers in repeating section when ever you can**

  - Use one time bindings : `{{::model}}`
  - Decrease using `ng-*` : all of them add a $watch.
  - Decrease using `$watchCollection` or `$watch`
  - Use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` : it removes dom and destroys watchers in.
  - Use `track by`: For large collections, this significantly improves rendering performance.
- **In Concatenating:**

  you could see [your problem in plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/dULgdw/) and next command

  ```
      [].push.apply($scope.list,getNewList());
  ```

  is better than

  ```
      $scope.list=$scope.list.concat(getNewList());
  ```

---

**But all above tips lets user have more items in the list but when number of items in the list get more than (let say 1000) the scrolling becomes slow again**

For this problem we could use Angular Material [md-virtual-repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat) which just load visible items on demand as i used in this [your problem with virtual repeat](https://embed.plnkr.co/U2mdBMzdrZuLEc2AoCJe/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should think about optimize your application, not just select a better directive or plugins, Too many scopes can also slow the application.