# Is it possible to use Angular infinite scroll and also sort table results?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll, columnsorting, large-data

There seems to be many third party libraries for infinity scrolling. I need a solution for Angular. I am needing to infinity scroll through 10k+ rows in my table and also have the capacity to sort those results by column. I have looked into ngInfiniteScroll, but it seems like sorting is out of the picture. Is there any hope for my plight? Angular gods. Throw me a bone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42502424/4790574 in that answer You have custom infinite scroll directive. You can add  Your filter to that code for sorting data. BUT performance of this operation...

Comment: You can look to https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat

Comment: Is data for your 10K+ rows is available to Angular at once? OR do you fetch from an API in smaller batches as user scrolls? -- Answer to your question depends on this.

Comment: 'Virtual scroll' is more correct name for what you need and sorting is not problem at all.